# WiFi works on Live USB but not on installation

Tags: networking

I'm trying to run Ubuntu 18.04 on a new desktop. When I installed from the live USB it was able to use wifi without any issues, but now that I'm in the OS, the networks fail to authenticate. I can still see the networks just fine, just whenever I enter the credentials and try to connect it just fails to connect. The real kicker is that it's definitely not an incorrect password, since the credentials were saved from when I used them on the live USB without issue!

The network is a university eduroam network if that helps at all.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: How were the credentials saved from a LiveUSB session? That seems unlikely without unusual effort. Or did you merely mean that the credentials were *tested* successfully in the Live session?

Comment: You can see more information with `sudo journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`